# I want to use few variables in other dart files. In short I want them to be globally accessed

Tags: flutter, dart, variables, global-variables, global

Here there are two bool variables I want them to be used in other dart files. How can I achieve that.
class EmployeeRegistrationScreen extends StatefulWidget {

```
  static const id = 'employee_register';

  @override
  _EmployeeRegistrationScreenState createState() => _EmployeeRegistrationScreenState();
}

class _EmployeeRegistrationScreenState extends State<EmployeeRegistrationScreen> {

  bool showSpinner = false;
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  String email;
  String password;
  String confirmPassword;
  bool  _passwordVisible = false;
  bool _confirmPasswordVisible = false;
  String name;
```

Comment: You can assign the variable outside of the class definition.

Comment: I have tried it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to access data on multiple screens, the [Provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) could help you. It stores global data accessible from all classes, without the need of creating constructors.

Here are some steps to use it (there is also a lot of info online):

- Import provider in pubspec.yaml
- Create your provider.dart file. For example:

  ```
  class HeroInfo with ChangeNotifier{
   String _hero = 'Ironman'

    get hero {
     return _hero;
    }

    set hero (String heroName) {
      _hero = heroName;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
  ```
- Wrap your MaterialApp (probably on main.dart) with ChangeNotifierProvider.

  ```
  return ChangeNotifierProvider(
    builder: (context) => HeroInfo(),
    child: MaterialApp(...),
  );
  ```
- Use it on your application! Call the provider inside any build method and get data:

  ```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    final heroProvider = Provider.of<HeroInfo>(context);

    return Column {
      children: [
        Text(heroProvider.hero) 
      ]
    }
  }
  ```
- Or set data:

  ```
  heroProvider.hero = 'Superman';
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at state management which will help app states between widgets. A good introduction by the Flutter team here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro